# Doubt on a proof involving a pseudo-metric and elementary topology.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**Exercise.** Let $d$ be a pseudo-metric in $X$ and for $A,B \subset X$ we have $d(A,B) = \text{inf}\{d(a,b): a \in A, b \in B\}$. Show that:

There is only one pseudo-metric in $X$ s.t. $\overline{A}=X \Leftrightarrow A \neq \emptyset$. For any other pseudo-metric there are infinitely many others that define the same closure.

**My attempt.** Let $O: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a pseudo-metric (trivial to prove) on $X$ s.t.
\begin{equation*}
O(A,B) = 0, \quad \forall A,B \in X
\end{equation*}
Let us now prove that the initially presented equivalence is valid.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume $\overline{A} = X$ and $A = \emptyset$. Then we obviously have that $\overline{A}=A=\emptyset \neq X$ (assuming that $X \neq \emptyset$) which is a contradiction and thus proving the first implication.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let us now suppose that $A \neq \emptyset$, i.e., $A$ contains at least one element. Let $a \in A$. For every $a' \in \overline{A}$ we either have that $a' \in A$ or $a' \in A'$. The case where $a' \in A$ obviously implies $a' \in X$, since $A \subset X.$ On the other hand, let $a' \in A'$. Then, by definition:
\begin{equation*}
\forall r>0, V_r(a') \hspace{.15cm} \cap \hspace{.15cm} A\backslash\{a'\} \neq \emptyset  
\end{equation*}
Putting $r\rightarrow 0$,  $a'$ will be as close as we want to an element of $A$, and since $A \subset X$ we can say that $a' \in X.$ We have just proved that $\overline{A} \subset X$.

**Doubts.** I am stuck on proving that $X \subset \overline{A}$ to complete the proof. But how can I show that a bigger set is contained on a subset of his own? I assume this is where the initially defined pseudo-metric comes in, but I don't know how to do it. Besides this, I am also having trouble proving the unicity of the affirmation (I know the standard process to do so would be assuming there's a metric $d'$ that verifies the equivalence and then showing that $d' = O$ in every possible scenario but I can't get to it). Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Have you deleted the other question on this? My answer there contained all the elements...

Comment: $x \in \overline{A}$ iff for all $r>0: V_r(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. No need for $A\setminus \{a\}$ stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the pseudo-metric $O$, the only open subsets are $\emptyset$ and $X$. Therefore, the only closed subsets are $\emptyset$ and $X$ too. So, if $A\ne\emptyset$, $\overline A=X$, since $X$ is the only closed subset containing $A$.

And if $\rho$ is any other pseudo-metric, then, for each $\lambda>0$, $\lambda\times\rho$ is another (distinct) pseudo-metric with respect to which the closed sets are the same as with $\rho$. Therefore, the closure of a set with respect to $\rho$ is equal to its closure with respect to $\lambda\times\rho$.

Comment: Why are the only open subsets $\emptyset$ and $X$ ? I don't understand it! Thanks for your time and help

Comment: If $x\in X$, the open ball centered at $x$ with any radius is the whole $X$. Since the only open ball is $X$, the only non-empty open set is $X$.

Comment: Makes sense to me! How would one prove that $\overline{A} = X \Rightarrow A \neq \emptyset$ ? Is my proof about this right? Thanks once again :D

Comment: Since $\overline\emptyset=\emptyset$, if $\overline A$ is anything other than $\emptyset$, $A\ne\emptyset$. Concerning your proof, I do not understand why is it that you write that “we obviously have that $\overline A=A$”.

Comment: Basically I assumed that $A = \emptyset$ and tried to go for a contradiction. In this case, we have (as you said) $\overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow \overline{A} = A$ (this is where it comes from) and thus (assuming $X$ is non-empty) we have a direct contradiction. I am just not sure about $X$ being non-empty. Thanks for your answers! Really clarified me

Comment: I'm glad I could help.